# Does Testcafe works with Superset?

Tags: testcafe

Does Testcafe works with Superset?
In my case, a browser window opens but nothing happens further - as if the testcafe does not see it.
I tried the latest versions 3.5.0 and 3.5.0-rc.1 but it did not help.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Hello,
Please use this [template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) to create a ticket and also share a [Minimal Working Example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402636/faq/general-info?search#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue) in that thread so that the TestCafe team can research the issue and help you.